# install Office 365, and also keep Office 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

friends,

I've searched for a similar question that might have the answer I need, but I'm not finding it. If my question has already been answered, please forgive, and I beg your pardon.

My client uses Windows 10 / Office 2007. Client wants me to update Office 2007 to the latest version of Office 365.

Can I install Office 365, and still keep Office 2007 installed? Client has a lot of email in Outlook 2007, contained in about a dozen small separate PST files . . . he must not lose this email.

Thank you for any advice.

Eric

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. It's supported to install Office 365 and Office 2007 side by side on the same computer. For more information, read [Supported scenarios for installing different versions of Office, Project, and Visio on the same computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer).

Answer (score 1):

> My client uses Windows 10 / Office 2007. Client wants me to update Office 2007 to the latest version of Office 365.

The process of installing Office 365 will not uninstall Office 2007 unless when prompted to remove Office 2007 you select that option.

> Can I install Office 365, and still keep Office 2007 installed?

Yes;  However, having multiple versions of Office installed, will likely confuse your client.

> Client has a lot of email in Outlook 2007, contained in about a dozen small separate PST files . . . he must not lose this email.

Your clients Outlook profile will be kept unless you delete it.  Likewise, the .PST files will remain, unless you delete them.  You should backup the files, if they are as critical as you make them sound.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can install multiple Office versions installed. BUT... You can only have one version of Outlook running at a time.

Also, see [Install and use different versions of Office on the same PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-and-use-different-versions-of-office-on-the-same-pc-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf) for details.